# Google Places / Business API - how to get special hours of any business?

Tags: google-places-api

I would like to get opening hours for places in Google Maps into the future, these are defined in the Google My Business as "special hours" (christmas, etc)

In the Google Places API https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details, it returns opening hours for this week only, no special hours. You can get special hours from the Google My Business API, but from what I gather it's only for businesses you administer, not for any business out there like you can get for Places. https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations

There's a 3 year old request to add special hours to the Places API, but yeah, 3 years old. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10145

Does anyone know of any method to get special hours for any Place ID out of Google?